# How can I remove an extra line, without using .rstrip

Tags: python

In my program, it keeps adding an extra line afterward because I have an int(input) and it needs to add the extra line if there is more than one input so that they won't be next to each other. But in the end, it keeps an extra line. But I can't use .rstrip because technically we haven't learned it in class. Is there any other way to remove the line.

so I have tried .rstrip but as I said before "it is too advanced right now" I have also tried using end= '' to try and get rid of the new line but there's always an error

```
large = int(input("Large Layers on bottom:\n"))

medium = int(input("Medium Layers on bottom:\n"))

front = int(input("Front length:\n"))

print(large * (space * 4 + "\\" + "-" * (front - 4) + "|\n"))

print(medium * (space * (front // 2) + ":" + "+" * (front // 2) + "|\n"))
```

I expected the output to have the two parts on top of each other without an added newline in between.

```
   \------|
   \------|
    :+++++|
    :+++++|
```

Here is a picture of what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfKYm.png

Comment: Can you tell us sample input for large medium and front, and the expected output

Comment: yeah for large and medium, a sample input is from 0 to 9 and for the front the input can be anywhere from 10 to 25. The expected output is for the large layer to on top of the medium layer with no add line in between

Comment: And what is the value of space?

Comment: In fact, can you show us a [mcve].  Note that this doesn't need to be your actual program, just the simplest complete program which shows your problem. (In particular, assign integer constants to large/medium/front, and show us the assignment to `space`)

Comment: it should just add blank spaces, it should just be: space = ' '

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: Add the actual output instead of the image @CiaVale

Comment: Independent of your problem you might want to read through [this page](https://pyformat.info/) to learn how to format string more easily.

Comment: @CiaVale you can actually avoid all this by using a list of strings and joining them back with a newline, and using string formatting

Answer (score 2):

```
print(large * (space * 4 + "\\" + "-" * (front - 4) + "|\n"), end='')
print(medium * (space * (front // 2) + ":" + "+" * (front // 2) + "|\n"), end='')
```

pass `end=''` as argument to your `print` functions (default is '\n').

As a side-note - look at using string formatting instead of string concatenation - it will improve the readability of your code.

EDIT: I updated my code to reflect the information provided by OP

Comment: I have to add them because if there is more than one input for each layer then they become side by side instead of on top of

Comment: @CiaVale, I updated my answer to reflect the additional information provided

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add the \n back - see it now